# Grails layouts and meta tags

Tags: grails

I defined a layout, myLayout that has a left and center content.
I apply my layout to all pages and the layout is composed of a series of other components (Another layout, templates ...)

In a page A, there is a component part of the layout that should not be displayed in the page. To solve that i had two solutions

1. define a new layout only for that page
   I didn't like to create a whole layout just for one page,
2. define a meta tag with a specific value in the page A and I used the *pageProperty* to check if the value is set and hide or show the component accordingly

The meta tag in page A index.gsp

```
<meta name="foo" content="myContent"/>
```

And myLayout

```
 <g:if test="${pageProperty(name:'meta.foo')!='myContent'}">    
 // Render template
</g:if>
```

is this a good way to deal with this problem ? is there a better way ?

- ken

Answer (score 0):

my vote is for pageProperty